# Must I release this image?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm creating an UIImage like this:

```
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Am I responsible for releasing this?

Comment: Usually you're only required to release something if you're actually the one who called alloc. If something comes from something like a class method then it is either autoreleased or the system should otherwise take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

> **Return Value**
>
> An autoreleased image
>   object containing the contents of the
>   current bitmap graphics context.

[(doc link)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW31). As it's written there, it returns an `autorelease`d object. You don't have to release it. If you want to keep it, you need to retain it somehow.